# Formatting JavaScript Textarea

Tags: javascript

I want to format input text in JavaScript so that newline characters are automatically appended at every end of line before the cursor moves to the next line, without the user having to press the 'Enter' key. Please how could this be achieved?

Comment: If you don't provide any code or anything to work with we can't really help.

Comment: what did you try?  show us, we will fix it

Comment: If the user doesn't press enter, how do you know when the end of the line even is?

Comment: Thanks for comments! I want every line in the textarea to be of specific length, after which a newline is appended. Thanks, once again!

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more information (like conditional when line will break)

At example, when entering text at the line have 50 characters, it will break line.

Add custom conditional for your code.

```
$('textarea').keypress(function () {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (length % 51 == 0 &&
       length > 0) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(val + '\n');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2QZbG/

Comment: Thanks for comments! I want every line in the textarea to be of specific length, after which a newline is appended. Thanks, once again!

Comment: My answer resolves your problem. Only limit specific length of `textarea`.